# Remove duplicate entries from ArrayList according to first char of string

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to remove a string from an array list whose first character is the same as another string's.

**Example**

```
List<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();

collection.add("1 w a");
collection.add("2 r a");
collection.add("1 r b");
collection.add("2 r b");
collection.add("3 w a");
```

**Output**

```
collection = ["1 w a", "2 r a", "3 w a"]
```

I tried using `hashset` and `linkedhashset`.

Comment: You could use a `Map`, mapping first chars to Strings although this may be overkill.

Comment: @Quirliom thanks. but i want to use ArrayList.

Comment: fill another ArrayList using this, and in a step add the first character to a separate `Set` and check the list for the next string's first character at each step. let me know if you are not getting the point clearly.

Comment: @Prateek but an ArrayList is the wrong data structure for this kind of task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minimal storage of first `character`, you can do find-and-remove-dups:

```
List<Character> dups = new ArrayList<Character>();
        Iterator<String> itr = collection.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            String s = itr.next();
            char c = s.charAt(0);
            if(dups.contains(c)) {
                itr.remove();
                continue;
            }
            dups.add(c);
        }
        System.out.println(collection);
```

**Output:**

[1 w a, 2 r a, 3 w a]

Answer (score 1):

The **ind** list contains the indices to be removed.

But the people commenting above are right, computationally i.e.
algorithmically viewed, you should use a better data structure 
here, rather than ArrayList.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Test005 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();
        collection.add("1 w a");
        collection.add("2 r a");
        collection.add("1 r b");
        collection.add("2 r b");
        collection.add("3 w a");

        List<Integer> ind = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i=0; i<collection.size(); i++){
            for (int j=0; j<i; j++){
                if (collection.get(j).charAt(0) == collection.get(i).charAt(0)){
                    ind.add(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int k=0; k<ind.size(); k++){
            collection.remove(ind.get(k).intValue());
        }

        for (int i=0; i<collection.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(collection.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you want to do is go through the list and for each element, go through the rest of the list and delete any that have the same startign character.

A sample implementation:

```
List<String> deleteList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0;i < collection.size();i ++){
    //If this is flagged for deletion continue
    if(deleteList.contains(collections.get(i)))continue; 
    for(int j = i + 1;j < collection.size();j ++){
        //If this is flagged for deletion continue
        if(deleteList.contains(collections.get(j)))continue;
        //If the chars are the same, add it to the list to be deleted
        if(collection.get(i).charAt(0) == collection.get(j).charAt(0)){
            deleteList.add(collection.get(j));
        }
    } 
}

collection.removeAll(deleteList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `TreeSet` with a `Comparator` that only looks at the first character. Insert all elements into the set.

```
 new TreeSet<String>(
   new Comparator<String>(){
     public int compare(String s1, String s2){
         if (s1 == null || s1.length() == 0)
            return (s2 == null || s2.length() == 0) ? 0 : 1;
         else if (s2 == null || s2.length == 0)
            return -1;
         else 
            return s1.substring(0,1).compareTo(s2.substring(0,1));
     }
 });
```

Comment: A `TreeSet` operates like any other `Set` in that it only allows one element that it considers to be "equal". The `Comparator` I provide, only looks at the first character of the `String`. It has some added complexity to handle the null / empty case. By providing this `Comparator` to the `TreeSet`, the `Set` will only keep the first `String` with a unique first character. Now simply add you collection of elements to the set.

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();

    collection.add("1 w a");
    collection.add("2 r a");
    collection.add("1 r b");
    collection.add("2 r b");
    collection.add("3 w a");

    Set set = new HashSet();
    for(int i=0;i<collection.size();++i){
        String temp = collection.get(i);
        if(set.contains(temp.charAt(0))){
            collection.remove(temp);
            i--;
        }  else{
            set.add(temp.charAt(0));
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<collection.size();++i){
        System.out.println(collection.get(i));
    }
```

output :

1 w a

2 r a

3 w a

Answer (score 0):

Going through every element of given List, With the help of a temporary set we are checking if the first element is in the set. if it is not then we are adding it in the final list. if it already contains that, then skip it.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();

    collection.add("1 w a");
    collection.add("2 r a");
    collection.add("1 r b");
    collection.add("2 r b");
    collection.add("3 w a");
    System.out.println(removeDuplicates(collection));
}

private static List<String> removeDuplicates(List<String> collection) {

    HashSet<String> withoutDuplicates = new HashSet<String>();
    List<String> collection2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String s : collection){
        String[]  temp = s.split(" ");

        if(!withoutDuplicates.contains(temp[0])){
            withoutDuplicates.add(temp[0]);
            collection2.add(s);
        }
    }
    return collection2;
}
}
```